# Deleted posts can be edited

Tags: discussion, bug, 10k-tools

I just earned the "Access Moderator Tools" privilege, and the first thing I did was have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694603/add-a-number-to-another-number-in-javascript). Then I noticed an edit button on the question and its answers. I [submitted an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2694647/revisions), thinking that an error would appear when I tried to submit, but it worked. Of course, I immediately rolled it back.

Is this by design? If so, why?

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to edit the post?  If you want to propose a new feature to prevent deleted questions from being edited, then you'll need to explain why you think that feature is worth implementing.

Comment: Deletion is not permanent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are cases in which this is useful:

- When link-based answers are deleted in review or by moderators, we often tell the answerer to edit the answer into shape and flag for undeletion.
- For those facing question bans due to closed and deleted questions, one way they can work themselves out of that is to edit and improve those questions, then have them undeleted.
- I've seen cases where another user edited an answer to clarify it and show that it wasn't a non-answer, just poorly worded, then flagged us for undeletion.
- Occasionally, highly offensive material is left behind in deleted posts that weren't flagged in a way that causes the system to automatically hide them. There might be cause to edit that out in those rare cases. We usually don't recommend this, but it has been useful on occasion.